# ArcGIS Dissolve/SQL group by

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, sql, dissolve

I have a GIS layer that has thousands of Facility IDs. For each Facility ID there can be multiple Chemical ID's. For each chemical ID there is a maximum of 3 zone types. Zone A, B, C. But there is not always 3 Zone types, it varies. And the amount of chemical ID's for each Facility ID can vary from 1 to many.  What I am attempting to do, is Dissolve this layer down to display which Facility ID Zone has the largest Buffer Distance while including the ZoneType(important)

Here are the fields

```
                FacilityID, ChemicalID, ZoneType, ZoneDistance
ex rows:        1              2           A          1000
                1              2           B          900
                1              2           C          500
                1              5           A          1200
                1              5           B          900
                1              7           B          2000
                1              7           C          900
                2              13          A          200
                2              13          B          300
                2              13          C          600
```

What i have tried:

I tried using the Dissolve tool to dissolve based on the FacilityID, ZoneType and my statistic field was the Max for the ZoneDistance. So the output of this dissolve is the Facility ID with the Max ZoneDistance for each ZoneType. I just want the Max ZoneDistance for all the ZoneTypes at a FacilityID.

I also tried SQL statement which I got the same results.

```
SELECT max(ZoneDistance), ZoneType, FacilityID
FROM AllZones group by ZoneType, FacilityID;
```

I am semi new to SQL, and I cannot seem to figure out the logic to get my results.

Comment: Can you display exactly how you would like your output displayed? I'm not quite following what you're after.

Comment: Yes I would like the result to be: 1 row for every FacilityID with the Max Buffer and that specific zone type. So for FacilityID 1- I want one row and it would be ZoneType B with a ZoneDistance of 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the Summary Statistics tool for this instead, it works like Dissolve but doesn't handle geometry, which you don't seem to need for this anyway.

In either case, the problem is the same: if you want to know the maximum ZoneDistance for each FacilityID, you should only be basing your dissolve on FacilityID. Adding ZoneType as a dissolve field will give you the max ZoneDistance for each unique combination of FacilityID and ZoneType.

If you need to know the ZoneType associated with the maximum value for each FacilityID, you can find that out after the Dissolve is done by joining the resulting layer to your original layer using a new join field you create by concatenating the FacilityID and ZoneDistance.

Comment: cool thanks that was a simpler than i thought..any chance you would know how to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your FacilityID-ChemicalID-ZoneDistance combinations are unique, you can create a field in both your original table and dissolved table that you can use to match the ZoneType back up to your dissolve records.

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Strickly looking for a SQL answer, you could try something like this (this is PostGreSQL syntax):

```
SELECT t1.facilityid, t2.zonetype, t1.maxzonedistance
   FROM (SELECT MAX(zonedistance) maxzonedistance, facilityid
             FROM __yourtablename__ GROUP BY facilityid) AS t1
   JOIN __yourtablename__ t2
   ON (t2.facilityid = t1.facilityid and t2.zonedistance = t1.maxzonedistance)
```

The logic behind is, that when using an aggregate function (such as max), all the other columns have to be in a group by. The way you wrote it, it will create groups for each unique value of the pair "facilityid + zonetype", resulting in multiple rows for each facilityid.

To counter that, I just joined the actual additionnal data (zonetype) from the table directly using the values obtained with the subquery. An easier way would have been to do the same but using a unique primary key that identifies each row..

Unless I am mistaken, this query should give you multiple records for facilityid = 1 if there are two zonedistance with the same value (lets say facilityid 1, chemicalid 4, zonetype C and zonedistance 2000). You decide what to do in that instance (if possible to have multiple results with the same (max)value).